# Keyboard navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, navigation, keyboard, accessibility

Android usually supports navigation with the `tab` and `enter` key as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation).

However, when using Jetpack compose this option seems unavailable. Is this true and if yes I wonder what would be the simplest method to navigate a Jetpack Compose Kotlin App using my keyboard?

maybe use the custom navigation as described [here](https://proandroiddev.com/accessibility-in-jetpack-compose-e2f280810cd) ?
or better implement a whole new navigation method as described [here](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/how-we-improved-keyboard-navigation-accessibility-in-our-android-sdk/)?

Thank you for any help